# Home screen icon not matching the app store icon

Tags: ios, app-store

I've uploaded an application to the app store with "version 1 app icon".

*This worked fine.*

A week later I've uploaded a new version of the app with "version 2 app icon".

The build icon + the app store icon shown on the `iTunes connect` are "version 2 app icon" but after downloading the app to my phone from the AppStore, I see on my home screen a "version 1 app icon".

Reminder - "version 1 icon", which I don't want to see on my home screen, was the icon of the previous app build and version.

**MORE INFO**

I'm using iPhone 6s and iOS 10.3.2.
I have multiple targets, with different app icons for each of targets.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: can you provide image?

Comment: images of what?

Comment: on macOS there is a IconService that caches all Icons. What did you try? Reboot? Unzip the IPA and check it's i inline icons?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the answer - 
I just hard clean the project and uploaded it again. This time it worked.